# Update DOM with div tag along with bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, bootstrap-4

```js
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
if(i%4===0){
            $("#image-album").append('<div class="row">');
          }
          
          $("#image-album").append('<div class="col-md-3">image '+i+'</div>')
         
          if(i!==0 && (i+1)%4===0){
            $("#image-album").append('</div>');
          }
          };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<span id="image-album">
</span>
```

I want to update my dom with jquery which contains bootstrap classes to display images in grid. But i am not able to add div with "row" class. I tried to do something as shown in the snippet.
Expect it to be:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
  image 1
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  image 2
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  image 3
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  image 4
 </div>
</div>
```

But it end up being:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col">
  image 1
</div>
<div class="col">
  image 2
</div>
<div class="col">
  image 3
</div>
<div class="col">
  image 4
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of "score" for the first 4 elements of data??

Comment: Post all of the relevant HTML... #results #image-album

Comment: @ZimSystem This seems like a bogus post, I don't have enough rep to close it. What do you think?

Comment: I have made some changes in my question. please let me know if my question is clear? @RyanWilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, build full HTML and then append to `span`

```js
let htlm ="";
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{

    if(i%4===0)
    {
       htlm +='<div class="row">';
    }
    htlm +='<div class="col-md-3">image '+i+'</div>';
    if(i%4===3)
    {
       htlm +='</div>';
    }
        
};
$("#image-album").append(htlm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<span id="image-album">
</span>
```

Comment: How do you know this will work?? Do you know the values of 'score' ???  The issue isn't closing the div element, it's wrapping the images inside the div with class row. it only adds the images if score is < 10 which since the OP hasn't provided that info, I highly doubt your solution will work.

Comment: I do not know the use of `score`

Comment: Then don't post an answer to this.

Comment: can you please review the question again i have made some changes

Comment: @RikeshShrestha I have updated code now it is working